# Parse SOAP webservice dynamically

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'd like to create an application where you can specify a webservice's url and automatically get the input parameters a output format. (similar to svcutil in Visual Studio I think), in the way the user could add webservices dynamically to the app and select which data is gonna send and what is he gonna do with the return data.

So it seems like I have to go through the WSDL, do you know any good reading or documentation about this? Or any advice from your experience? :)

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com)? They have some tutorials on WSDL, SOAP and Web Services which might get you started.

Answer (score 1):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) inspects and invokes web services.